# Fluent NHibernate ManyToOne Reference Property Name issue

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I was using `Fluent NHibernate` and I had these two `entities`:

```
public class Location
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    private Stack<Place> _places;
    public virtual IList<Place> Places
    {
        get { return _places.ToList(); }
        set { _places = new Stack<Place>(value); }
    }
    public virtual void AddPlace(Place place)
    {
        _places.Push(place);
        place.LocationReference = this;
    }
}

public class Place
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Location LocationReference { get; set; }
}
```

`mapped` as follow:

```
class LocationMap : ClassMap<Location>
{
    public LocationMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Unique();
        HasMany(x => x.Places)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse();
    }
}

class PlaceMap : ClassMap<Place>
{
    public PlaceMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.LocationReference);
    }
}
```

I was using `SQLite` as `RDBMS` and I was saving only the `Location`, relying on `Cascade()` for managing `Places` insertion.

The two entities were successfully inserted in the DB, but when I tried to read a `Location` back and to access its list of `Places`, the list was empty.

After removing `Inverse()`, the code seemed to properly work. But when I inspected the DB, I found two columns within the `Place table`, while I expected only one of them: `Location_id` (that was empty) and `LocationReference_id` (that was set).

After one whole day of desperate googling, I noticed that everyone was naming the reference `property` as the class itself. So, I renamed it from `LocationReference` to `Location`, I added back the `Inverse()` call and everything worked fine. Only the column `Location_id` was in the DB, of course.

Does anyone know why this happened? Thanks.